# Bulk delete E-Mails with condition

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

One application sent me 18000 E-Mails during the weekend. Is there a way to bulk delete all Messages depending on a condition? I had around 120 E-Mails that should not be deleted.

The E-Mails were sent from `Unique User Name <notuniqueemailadress@xy.com>`. is there a way to tell outlook to delete all E-Mails from `Unique User Name` that are in my inbox?

I could just CTRL + A all E-Mails and delete them but I want to be sure to only select those I really want to delete. I also need to be sure that "real" E-Mails that are between the 18000 E-Mails don't get deleted.

I also have Admin Access to our Microsoft 365 / Exchange Online Portals if there is a way to delete them there.

Comment: You could simply create a rule that does this, in the rule you could move the emails to a new folder, then execute the rule on existing emails. This way, you can make sure all goes well before committing to it fully. You would then of course delete that new folder and delete the rule. You can also directly delete using a rule. Alternatively, create a search folder with your criterea and delete from there.

Comment: @LPChip nice idea. right now I'm letting PowerShell delete the Mails... let's see what happens :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used PowerShell for this task

First you need to connect to [Exchange Online](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps)

I wanted to be sure to only Delete the E-Mails I really want to delete. I was able to ensure this by using the following Command, which sent me a log to the target mailbox.

`Search-Mailbox -Identity me@xy.com -SearchQuery 'Subject:"Subject of Mails"' -TargetMailbox foo@xy.com -TargetFolder Inbox`

Then you can just add the `-DeleteContent` Switch to delete the E-Mails it found

`Search-Mailbox -Identity me@xy.com -SearchQuery 'Subject:"Subject of Mails"' -TargetMailbox foo@xy.com -TargetFolder Inbox -DeleteContent`

I had to run this twice since `Search-Mailbox` will only return 10000 results/E-Mails.

If you read this after April 1st 2020, this cmdlet is not supported anymore. It may still work but there's no guarantee.

@LPChip had a great alternative. Just create a rule that will copy your targeted E-Mails to a folder, and delete them from there.